# Question regarding open covers, closed intervals and rationals

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

i wanted to know if open neighbourhoods of arbitrarily small size around the rationals in a closed interval in R can constitute an open cover for the closed interval. I want to use this in a proof in a question from a Rudin book. Please do let me know,
Thanks,
Kind regards,
Sachin

Comment: Not necessarily. For example, for $[0,1]$  it would be easy to insure none of the open intervals contains $1/\sqrt2$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Does this closed interval $I \subseteq$ the cover, or should it be $I =$ cover?

Comment: You asked "can it constitute an open cover for the closed interval", but I think what you meant is "Does it necessarily constitute an open cover for the closed interval?" Am I right?

Comment: Thanks, everybody. I get it now. I did mean "can", that is " is there at least one way in which i can ensure the result". Anyway, i wanted to know if i can cover the interval [0, 1], using arbitrarily small neighborhoods around the rationals, including the end points in the given interval. From what i gather from your replies it should be possible. Thanks, once again.